# Setting region label color/attributes for jvectormap

Tags: label, region, jvectormap

is there a way to vary the region label color based upon the value for a region much like you would set the region fill color based upon a set of values? is there an onRegionLabelShow function? I've seen it referenced elsewhere throughout the web but its not in the documentation at http://jvectormap.com/ or setting the html of the label?

Comment: did you find any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

I added custom label styles to the library in this pull request: https://github.com/bjornd/jvectormap/pull/409